# Dropdown menu not appearing - Rails4+boostrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my _header.html.erb, I have the following:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown'>
        Journal Entries
        <b class='caret'></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><%= link_to "List all Journal Entries", sournal_entries_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "New Journal Entry", new_journal_entry_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

In my application.js, I have the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
//= require google-code-prettify
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The menu item (Journal Entries) appears, with a carret next to it, but clicking on the carret or the menu item does nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turbolinks was the problem. When I removed it from application.js (as well as the gem), dropdown started working fine